# mysql warning : primary key and index on the same field in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, indexing

> mysql warning : primary key and index on the same field in MYSQL .

As in theory books these two terms are used to explain indices, but in practice, when I try to make index on particular field which is also a primary key, then MySQL generates a warning, although the index is created.

Could anyone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A primary key already implies an index on the set of columns that make up the key, therefore a second (separate) index [is redundant](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-primary-keys.html):

> The primary key for a table represents the column or set of columns
>   that you use in your most vital queries. It has an associated index,
>   for fast query performance.

So by creating an explicit index you don't gain anything but on the contrary saddle the database with the responsibility of having to maintain two separate indexes.

Comment: but i tested that while using index on my own the performance improves

Comment: @ParveezAhmed: That's not saying anything. If you post your test with full details such that people could reproduce your result then we could start talking about it.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL automatically places an index on primary key fields. Adding your own index for that field is therefore unnecessary.

Comment: but i tested that while using index on my own the performance improves

Comment: What index did you add?

Comment: simple index. i used: create index ix on cities(city)

Comment: I don't have an immediate answer as to why that would be faster, I suggest you ask a new question to get an answer to that question, since this question has a different subject.